# column header viewport doesn't scroll

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I have a list in a scrollpane. The list fills with Strings that are longer than the list viewport, so I get horizontal scrolling OK. When I tried to add a columnheaderviewport with a label, that viewport won't scroll with the main viewport. It tries to scroll, flashing where the label text should be, but immediately returning to the default size/view.

Is using a column header only for scrollpanes with tables inside? That's the only examples I can find on the 'net. The java doc tutorials say nothing about tables only, and the column header should track the main viewport.

I'm using JDK 1.7 and Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

In the process of writing a small example, I inadvertently increased the amount of text in the label to more than what the label would display. Then the viewport started scrolling, tracking the main viewport scroll. I had read that the component in the column header viewport had to be same width as the main viewport, but apparently it's the content, not the component size that matters.

So, yes, a column header viewport can be scrollable with a list, not just tables.

Comment: *"So, yes, a column header viewport can be scrollable with a list, not just tables"* - That part we knew. *"but apparently it's the content, not the component size that matter"* - Is a contradiction, the size of the component should be directly related it's content